# Functional Component to display input fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

I have a simple form in react JS. I would like users to have an option to choose between **Phone Number** or **Email Address** based on preference.

For Example:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <label class="my-1 mr-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">
   How should we contact you ?? 
  </label>
   <select class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">Phone Number</option>
    <option value="2">Email</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

I would like to display either of these below fields:

```
  <input onChange={(event) => setPhone(event.target.value)} /> // <-- display this if a user choose Phone

  <input onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)} /> // <-- display this if a user choose Email
```

This is currently how I have written the code, I intend to fill the form and use that data when the **handleSubmit** takes place.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Checkout({ cart }) {
  let textInput = React.createRef();

  function handleClick() {
    console.log(textInput.current.value);
  }

  const [title, setName] = useState("");
  const [contactPreference, setContactPreference] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    const token = "fb83b937-2739-3d6e-9519-09387b92dfae";
    const data = {
      transactionReference: "string",
      paymentMethod: "CreditCard",
      checkoutOrderUrl: "http://www.test.com/",
      user: {
        name: "", // this is where the name from input field needs to be used
        msisdn: "+27610983142", // this is where the phone number from input field needs to be used
        email: "test@test.com", // this is where the email from input field needs to be used
      },
      payementMethodDetail: {
        RedirectUrl: "http://www.test.com",
        PurchaseEventWebhookUrl: "http://www.test.com",
      },

      bundle: cart.map((item) => ({
        ProductCode: `${item.ProductCode}`,
        Amount: item.amount,
        CurrencyCode: item.currencyCode,
        Quantity: item.quantity,
      })),
    };
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    };
    fetch(
      "https://api.flash-internal.flash-group.com/ecommerceManagement/1.0.0/api/checkout/",
      requestOptions
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => console.log(res));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Post items
      </button>
      <div>
        Name: <input onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)} />
        <form class="form-inline">
          <label class="my-1 mr-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">
            How should we contact you ??
          </label>
          <select
            onChange={(e) => {
              setContactPreference(e.target.value);
            }}
            class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2"
            id="inlineFormCustomSelectPref"
          >
            <option selected>Choose...</option>
            <option value="phone">Phone Number</option>
            <option value="email">Email</option>
          </select>
          {contactPreference === "phone" ? (
            <input
              placeholder="Enter your phone number."
              onChange={(event) => setPhone(event.target.value)}
            />
          ) : contactPreference === "email" ? (
            <input
              placeholder="Enter your email address."
              onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
            />
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Checkout;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, just store their preference option in state and then display the corresponding input field.

```
    const [contactPreference, setContactPreference] = useState("");
    const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    return (
        <div>
            <form class="form-inline">
                <label class="my-1 mr-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">
                    How should we contact you ??
                </label>
                <select
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        setContactPreference(e.target.value);
                    }}
                    class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2"
                    id="inlineFormCustomSelectPref"
                >
                    <option selected>Choose...</option>
                    <option value="phone">Phone Number</option>
                    <option value="email">Email</option>
                </select>
                {contactPreference === "phone" ? (
                    <input
                        placeholder="Enter your phone number."
                        onChange={(event) => setPhone(event.target.value)}
                    />
                ) : contactPreference === "email" ? (
                    <input
                        placeholder="Enter your email address."
                        onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
                    />
                ) : (
                    <></>
                )}
            </form>
        </div>
    );
```

Use the collected data in a POST request by changing the following:

```
    user: {
                name: name, // remember to change the useState declaration
                msisdn: phone, 
                email: email, 
            },
```

You should change

```
    const [title, setName] = useState("");
```

to

```
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
```

Comment: Benjamin, how can I then store the values and reuse them elsewhere. For example: emailAddress={email}.

I would like to use that information in on user details to be used on a POST request.

I have added another piece of code to my question on where the values need to be used.

Please look at the code I have attached.

Comment: Hey there, I can't see the additional code but all you have to do to access the values is call the respective variable name (email or phone). It depends on your component hierarchy on how to do it but if you are using a the collected data in a component below this one, just pass it down as props. It's customary on Stack Overflow to click the check mark if an answer answered your question, I'd greatly appreciate if you did so! Thanks

Comment: No worries, just added code to answer your edits